# Django Datetime not saved correctly

Tags: django, datetime

I made a calendar in django where I can save events with start and end dates. If I save a new event and enter for example the date '2015-01-11' it saves '2015-01-10'. So everytime I enter a date it is saved in the database -1 day.

here is my model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

here is my form:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'start', 'end']
```

here I save the new event that is passed via the form

```
event = Event(
    title=request.POST['title'],
    start=request.POST['start'],
    end=request.POST['end'],
)
event.save()
```

the date I input in the form is formatted like "%Y-%m-%d" ... for example '2015-01-12'.

Oh and it just affects the start date (not the end date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#time-zone) setting to match the system time zone.

Comment: unfortunately that does not fix the bug :(

Comment: What happens then you set `USE_TZ` to `False`?

Comment: that works :) but I guess I want to have USE_TZ enabled in the future. How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh, timezones in django is a some kind of black magic :-)  Do you have `pytz` installed? AFAIK it is very recommended.

Comment: yes it is installed. the calendar will be use by people in different timezones, so this could be inportant to be aware of timezones. Do you have some tips for me?

Comment: I think I can't be more helpful than this topic in django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/  BTW, see the third question in the "Troubleshooting" section: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/#troubleshooting